# How to adjust the compiler for c++11 on 10.8

Tags: macos, xcode

Originally, I posted my question on Stack Overflow.[Compile R package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33858596/installing-package-on-r-need-c11-support-for-osx) It seems that when installing the *R library(Boom)* I always get that error relating to compile error:

> fatal error: 'future' file not found include  1 error generated

So I thought that might be the solution, where Michael suggests to change the compiler by simply telling "the compiler to use it using -stdlib=libc++ and tell the linker to link against it using -lc++." Source: [Blog](http://blog.michael.kuron-germany.de/2013/02/using-c11-on-mac-os-x-10-8/)

I'm somehow lost on that and can't really implement it. May I ask for some assistance?

I tried that as well:

`wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zeromq/cppzmq/master/zmq.hpp`

`mv zmq.hpp /usr/local/include/`

I'm using Mac OSX 10.8.5 with Xcode version: 5.1.0, Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.6.0.

Here is the [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Boom/index.html) to the Boom package,a C++ library for Bayesian modeling.

Comment: This question belongs on StackOverflow.

Comment: Why is that? I just ask how to adjust the compiler on 10.8.6

Comment: This is clearly on topic here. Whether it fits on SO is irrelevant unless the asker wants it moved there. @ Googme - can you link to the boom package specifically or list the steps you follow to download and install this on a new user on the Mac in question? Also - are you OK with R 3.2.1 or do you need to work through the issues in porting the newer R onto an older OS and toolchain?

Comment: Hi @ bmike, yes I'm Ok with R 3.2.1. I used install.packages("Boom") Because the package itself is on CRAN. So it seems therefore, that my C++ compiler might be the issue. Originally, I had installed the Command Line Tools as well as Xcode. And marco from SO (above link) has related that to "This is almost certainly due to the missing --std=c++11 flag" which I do not fully understand even after spending hours with googling.

Comment: Perfect, I might have time to try and reproduce your error. Getting compiler flags to be included is a bit of a pain if you're not up on how a specific package likes to construct the compiler options.